# gcc installation on CentOS 6.6: configure issue

Tags: centos, gcc

I'm trying to build/install gcc on CentOS6.6, following this instructions:

[How to Install Qt 5 and Qwt on CentOS 6](http://qt-project.org/wiki/How-to-Install-Qt-5-and-Qwt-on-CentOS-6)

After the auto-config err'ed out:

```
[felix@localhost objdir]$ /home/felix/workspace/gcc-4.8.4/configure --prefix=$HOME/gcc-4.8.4
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln works... yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc... no
checking for gnatbind... no
checking for gnatmake... no
checking whether compiler driver understands Ada... no
checking how to compare bootstrapped objects... cmp --ignore-initial=16 $$f1 $$f2
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for version 0.10 of ISL... no
checking for version 0.11 of ISL... no
checking for version 0.12 of ISL... no
checking for version 0.14 of ISL... no
checking for default BUILD_CONFIG... 
checking for bison... bison -y
checking for bison... bison
checking for gm4... no
checking for gnum4... no
checking for m4... m4
checking for flex... flex
checking for flex... flex
checking for makeinfo... no
/home/felix/workspace/gcc-4.8.4/configure: line 7993: /missing: No such file or directory
checking for expect... no
checking for runtest... no
checking for ar... ar
checking for as... as
checking for dlltool... no
checking for ld... ld
checking for lipo... no
checking for nm... nm
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for strip... strip
checking for windres... no
checking for windmc... no
checking for objcopy... objcopy
checking for objdump... objdump
checking for readelf... readelf
checking for cc... cc
checking for c++... c++
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for gcj... no
checking for gfortran... gfortran
checking for gccgo... no
checking for ar... ar
checking for as... as
checking for dlltool... no
checking for ld... ld
checking for lipo... no
checking for nm... nm
checking for objdump... objdump
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for readelf... readelf
checking for strip... strip
checking for windres... no
checking for windmc... no
checking where to find the target ar... host tool
checking where to find the target as... host tool
checking where to find the target cc... host tool
checking where to find the target c++... host tool
checking where to find the target c++ for libstdc++... host tool
checking where to find the target dlltool... host tool
checking where to find the target gcc... host tool
checking where to find the target gcj... host tool
checking where to find the target gfortran... host tool
checking where to find the target gccgo... host tool
checking where to find the target ld... host tool
checking where to find the target lipo... host tool
checking where to find the target nm... host tool
checking where to find the target objdump... host tool
checking where to find the target ranlib... host tool
checking where to find the target readelf... host tool
checking where to find the target strip... host tool
checking where to find the target windres... host tool
checking where to find the target windmc... host tool
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: error: cannot find input file: `Makefile.in'
```

But Makefile.in is present

```
[felix@localhost gcc-4.8.4]$ ls Makefile.*
Makefile.def  Makefile.in  Makefile.tpl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid conflicts with installed software, it is advisable to
package self compiled software as well. The package manager then
performs consistency checks and it will prevent many common
accidents. Also, changes to the build can be kept under version
control.

Since the question pertains to CentOS, best grab a premade source
package [from Fedora](https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/packageinfo?packageID=40)
-- the distros are sufficiently similar -- and build it with
[rpmbuild](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SetupRpmBuildEnvironment).
Modify the RPM spec file to your liking if you need to tweak the
build process (regarding GCC, you probably don’t need all the
targets or frontends).

Answer (score 0):

It seems the recommended practice is to install some pre-baked devtoolset instead of building your own.

I followed this post:

https://superuser.com/questions/381160/how-to-install-gcc-4-7-x-4-8-x-on-centos

The repo URL seems to be outdated, so a bit search led to toolset made by CERN: 
http://linuxtoolkit.blogspot.ca/2014/11/install-gcc-481-and-other-scientitic.html

Answer (score 0):

Reading your post, my first impression is that it's looking for `Makefile.in` in `./` rather than relative to `configure` itself. Try:

```
cd /home/felix/workspace/gcc-4.8.4/
./configure --prefix=$HOME/gcc-4.8.4
```